# Same form with two different modeltypes c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, view, model

I am trying to create a form for customers to fill in their information in in ASP.NET C#. I am also trying to create the same form with same information for people in customer service who can fill in the form on customers behalf.
I am using two different models for it which esentially only differ in ValidationError messages.

The hard way to do this is create two very long forms in View with same information, with both being:

```
@model ModelType1 (or ModelType2)
<form id="form" action="@Url.Action("Form", "Home")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
@Html.ValidationMessageForFor(m => m.Name)
</div>

[..]

<div>
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Info23)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Info23
@Html.ValidationMessageForFor(m => m.Info23)
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Send Request">
```

Is there way I can edit in Controller which Modeltype I will use in this View so I won't have to create the same long form twice?

Comment: Create a base class for common code.   The have two classes that inherit the base class for the two model types.

Comment: No need to create 2 long forms if you're using MVC HTML helpers. Use a partial view with single model class sharing common properties & 2 others which have distinct properties which inherits shared class.

Comment: I am using this already, but the values which are separate are multiple, so partial view would only fix part of the issue.